# how to move the circles with for loop?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, geometry, ellipse

I wanna have six linearly moving dots -- three of them horizontally, others vertically using an array.

here is my code:

```js
let c;
let cspeed = 4 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  c=0
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 
  ellipse(c, height / 4, 50, 50);
  ellipse(c, height / 2, 50, 50);
  ellipse(c, height / 9, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 4, c, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 2, c, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 9, c, 50, 50);
  c+=cspeed;

  if (c > width || c < 0) {
    cspeed *= -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK, they do move. What is your question?

Comment: thanx, I wanna code efficiently:) so how could I use 'array' when moving those dots?:)

Comment: You can make array of objects, where every object has fields like `c_x, c_y, radius, color, vel_x, vel_y` and treat these objects in the loop

Comment: thanx a lot ! but im not sure yet,,,TTsorry,, could u show me the code..??

Comment: `let circles = [{"cx":0, "cy":0, "vx",1;"vy":0},{"cx":1, "cy":2, "vx":0,"vy":1}]`

Comment: hmm u mean 
````
let c;
let cspeed = 4 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  c=0
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 
  let circles = [{"cx":0, "cy":0, "vx",1;"vy":0},{"cx":1, "cy":2, "vx":0,"vy":1}]
  c+=cspeed;

  if (c > width || c < 0) {
    cspeed *= -1;
  }
}
```
what if I want to use something like i[ ] <-this....?

Comment: if (circles[i].cx>width || circles[i].cx < 0)  {circles.vx *= -1}

Comment: let c;
let cspeed = 4 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  c=0
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  let ellipse = [{"cx":0, "cy":0, "vx",1;"vy":0},{"cx":1, "cy":2, "vx":0,"vy":1}]
  c+=cspeed;


  if (circles[i].cx>width || circles[i].cx < 0) {circles.vx *= -1}
  }
}

Comment: sorry but it's not working to me,, could u show me the whole code..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another version of your code that incorporates an array.

```js
let height = 400;
let width = 500;
let s = 4;
let d = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(width, height);
}

let dots = [{
    y: height / 4,
    x: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'h'
  },
  {
    y: height / 2,
    x: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'h'
  },
  {
    y: height / 9,
    x: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'h'
  },
  {
    x: width / 4,
    y: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'v'
  },
  {
    x: width / 2,
    y: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'v'
  },
  {
    x: width / 9,
    y: 0,
    s: s,
    d: d,
    direction: 'v'
  },
]

function draw() {
  background(220);

  dots.forEach((dot) => {
    ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, dot.d, dot.d);
    if (dot.direction === 'h') {
      dot.x += dot.s

      if (dot.x > width || dot.x < 0) {
        dot.s *= -1;
      }
    } else if (dot.direction === 'v') {
      dot.y += dot.s

      if (dot.y > height || dot.y < 0) {
        dot.s *= -1;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank..! but i wanna make my code shorter..! i think i should use 'for loop'..!
could u help me how to use 'for loop' with those ellipse?

Comment: You can get inspiration from this snippet. It has quite more features than the original, if you `dumb it down` it could end up being shorter. But you hard code the points in 1 line and have 1 rule for the movement. There should be no significantly shorter way while keeping readability up

Comment: thnk for ur kindness helping...TT i have a question related to this code(i coded more but x)  it will be so thankful if u could check my code..! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718133/how-to-make-the-game-stops-if-object-hit-the-other