# How to make the game stops if object hit the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, p5.js

I was making a dodge ball game with p5js:) the player can move a yellow circle from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the canvas using the arrow keys, while dodging six linearly moving red dots -- three of them horizontally, others vertically.

all I want is
-> if the yellow dot hits one of the red dots, the game stops and the background turns black.

```
let c;
let cspeed = 4
let x= 25;
let y = 25;
let level=0;
let width = 800
let height = 800

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  c=0
  let d = dist(c,height/4,x,y); //becuz of 'dist is not defined' issue, i moved it to setup() position
  let e = dist(c,height/2,x,y);
  let f = dist(c,height/9,x,y);
  let g = dist(height/2,c,x,y);
  let h = dist(height/4,c, x,y);
  let j = dist(height/9,c, x,y);
  print(d);
  print(e); 
  print(f);
  print(g);
  print(h); 
  print(j); 
  if (d<20||e<20||f<20||g<20||j<20);{
    loseScreen();
}
}

function draw() {
  keyPressed()
  background(220);
  fill(50);
  textSize(30)
  text(level, 770, 30);
  

  fill('green')
  square(0, 0, 50);
  fill('purple');
  square(750, 750, 50);
  fill('yellow')
  ellipse(x, y, 40);
  
  
  c+=cspeed;
  fill('red');
  noStroke();   
  ellipse(c, height / 4, 50, 50);
  ellipse(c, height / 2, 50, 50);
  ellipse(c, height / 9, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 4, c, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 2, c, 50, 50);
  ellipse(height / 9, c, 50, 50);
    if (c > width || c < 0) {
    cspeed *= -1;
  }
    
}
  if (c > width || c < 0) {
    cspeed *= -1;
  }
  if (x > 770 && y >770){
   x = 25
   y= 25;
    cspeed *= 1.5
    level++;
  }
function loseScreen(){ // it's not working,,
  noStroke(); 
  fill('black');
  square(0,0,800); 
}

function keyPressed() {
  //print(keyCode, key);
  
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW && keyIsPressed) {
    x = x - 5;
    if (x<20){
      x=20
    }
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW&& keyIsPressed) {
     x = x + 5;
    if (x>780){
      x=780
    }
  } else if(keyCode == DOWN_ARROW&& keyIsPressed){
     y = y + 5; 
      if (y>780){
        y=780
      }
  }else if(keyCode == UP_ARROW&& keyIsPressed){
     y = y - 5; 
     if (y<20){
        y=20
      }
  }
}
```

here's my p5js code
https://editor.p5js.org/kiskl/sketches/XzwAM5pDA

I will appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: I think you have to calculate the distance between yellow and reds for each frame.
You can do that using a simple pythagorean theorem.
If distance <= radius yellow + red then isLost = true

Comment: Sorry,,,,I'm trying but i can't figure it out TT,,,,

Comment: Figure out what ? What i'm saying or the general problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: This course pretty much covers everything you want, I believe. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyqbNFMDRGQ

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin, thnx for ur advice! Now I used <dist> to set the distance between them but Idk why it's not working TT Could u check it for a bit?? i edited my code! thanks!

Comment: @rose, the can come from your function dist, but please note its placement. It only runs when the direction is vertical and when dot.y > height || dot.y < 0. This is not the way to go because this last condition should be true only when you have to change direction ie go back. You should place the checks in global scope of your forEach, ie put it as the start or the end. Moreover, does the red dots move ? I dont understand how they could with this implementation. I think you should replace by dots = dots.map(...), no ?

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin 
i fixed after ur comment but i got an issue called 'dist is not defined'..! and I'm not sure whether screen will be stop after my dist() ...! hmm could u check it a bit?? thanx TT 
https://editor.p5js.org/kiskl/sketches/ykQ95_bFE

Comment: If dist is not defined you have to define it ! (sometimes scope is not good but from what i see from the link you provided you did not define it). A simple pythagorean theorem should be enough =) You are on the good way, good luck !

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin   thanx! i moved them to set up()position, and there's no issue rn, but it's not working --> loseScreen(); when yellow hits the other reds, the screen should stop,,,TT sorry could u read at them a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your request, I expanded on the answer to your first question. The trick with my previous solution and why it is generally better to use arrays for things like this is that you can check collision for each dot with a couple of lines in the for loop.

Now there definitely is a benefit in using array over hard-coded points.

```js
let height = 700;
let width = 700;
let s = 4;
let d = 50;

let gamestate = 'running';

let level = 0;
let x = 25;
let y = 25;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(width, height);
}

let dots = [
  {y: height / 4, x: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'h' },
  { y: height / 2, x: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'h' },
  { y: height / 9, x: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'h' },
  { x: width / 4, y: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'v' },
  { x: width / 2, y: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'v' },
  { x: width / 9, y: 0, s: s, d: d, direction: 'v' },
]

function draw() {
  switch (gamestate) {
    case 'victory':
      victoryScreen();
      break;
    case 'lose':
      loseScreen();
      break;
    default:
      keyPressed();
      background(220);
      fill(50);
      textSize(30)
      text(level, 770, 30);


      fill('green');
      square(0, 0, d);
      fill('purple');
      square(width - d, height - d, d);
      fill('yellow');
      ellipse(x, y, 40);

      dots.forEach((dot) => {
        fill('red')
        ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, dot.d, dot.d);
        if (dot.direction === 'h') {
          dot.x += dot.s

          if (dot.x > width || dot.x < 0) {
            dot.s *= -1;
          }
        } else if (dot.direction === 'v') {
          dot.y += dot.s

          if (dot.y > height || dot.y < 0) {
            dot.s *= -1;
          }
        }

        if (x < (dot.x + d) && (dot.x - d) < x) {
          if (y < (dot.y + d) && (dot.y - d) < y) {
            gamestate = 'lose';
          }
        }
      });

      if (x > width - d && y > height - d) {
        gamestate = 'victory'
      }
  }
}


function loseScreen() {
  noStroke();
  fill('black');
  square(0, 0, 800);
}

function victoryScreen() {
  noStroke();
  fill('green');
  square(0, 0, 800);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW && keyIsPressed) {
    x = x - 5;
    if (x < d / 2) {
      x = d / 2;
    }
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW && keyIsPressed) {
    x = x + 5;
    if (x > (width - d / 2)) {
      x = width - d / 2;
    }
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW && keyIsPressed) {
    y = y + 5;
    if (y > (height - d / 2)) {
      y = height - d / 2;
    }
  } else if (keyCode == UP_ARROW && keyIsPressed) {
    y = y - 5;
    if (y < d / 2) {
      y = d / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow.........thank you so much....!!! i finally understand ur code 100%..!!! thank you !!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/72752571/… sorry but could u check this one for a bit..?? thnx! –@nestoro

Comment: Don't use else-if statements, the controls are very awkward. Instead just use if statements. Even if thats not what they wanted, using a switch statement would still be better.